# What is the difference between in_array() and array_key_exists()?

Tags: php, arrays

I am having doubt here. Actually, what is the difference between `in_array()` and `array_key_exists()`. I have tried to find this, but still I confused. Can I get one sample??

Thanks.

Comment: You mean `array_key_exists` ?

Comment: yes ofcourse. its array_key_exists().

Comment: And what you didn't understand within these questions

Comment: I just want to know the difference

Comment: look for official info http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php its all quite clear explained

Comment: @Sreedevi  check the answers below. Mark one which is more correct.Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### `in_array()` <sub><sup>*versus*</sup></sub> `array_key_exists()`

***Difference:***

- [**`in_array()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) checks if a **value** exists in an array ***(checks the values, not the keys)*** and returns `true`, or `false` otherwise.

*while:*

- [**`array_key_exists()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) checks if the given **key** or **index** exists in the array ***(checks in keys, not in values)*** and returns `true`, or `false` otherwise.

Visits the manual (links above) for examples and more information.

An example link: https://eval.in/602279

Comment: Sree devi  you have all the answers. check them and which one is more suitable for you,mark and up-vote that one. If others are useful also. up-vote them also.thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just my two cents:

**First**
`in_array` will check the existance of the given parameter among an array values, meaning that it will ignore the array keys if searching against an associative array.

**Second**
`in_array` accepts a third parameter (TRUE or FALSE, FALSE by default) to use strict type comparison. If you omit this parameter, it will happen that:

```
in_array(0,[false]) => true (0 is coerced to boolean for loose comparison)
in_array(1,['1 person']) => true ('1 person' is coerced as numeric until the first non numeric character)
in_array('',[null]) => true (again, string is coerced).
```

**Third**
You can check if an array contains another array:

```
in_array([1,2],[[1,2], [3,4]]) => true
```

**Fourth**
`array_key_exists` will search among the array keys. If the array is non associative, the numeric index of each element is the key:

```
array_key_exists(0,[1,2,3]) => true (there is an element at index 0)
```

However, the usual case is to search for a string key:

```
array_key_exists('two',['one'=>1, 'two'=>2]) => true (there is an element with key 'two')
```

The comparison is not *really* strict, meaning that

```
array_key_exists(0,['0'=>1, 'two'=>2]) => true
```

But this is [explained in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Array keys are coerced to numeric if they are either strings containing only numbers (optionally, with a decimal separator), boolean or float numbers. NULL is casted to an empty string. So the keys might be either integers or strings. Aside from that implicit conversion, the following is false:

```
array_key_exists(1,['1 person'=>1, 'two'=>2]) => false
```

**Finally**, `in_array` performs a sequential scan on the array contents, whereas `array_key_exists` performs a search against a hash table. This means the performance of the latter is constant no matter the size of the array you're searching, whereas `in_array` speed is proportional to the array size. So if you're doing

```
in_array('one', array_keys(['one'=>1, 'two'=>2]))
```

You really **really** should be doing

```
array_key_exists('one', ['one'=>1, 'two'=>2])
```

Answer (score 1):

In array search in values of arary while array_key_exist() check key is exist and return 
like

```
$arr=["a"=>1,"b"=>2,"c"=>3,4,5,6];
// now you need to search 5 in $arr then you need to use  in_array()
// and array_key_exists() check if key exist in array 
in_array(5);  //return true
array_key_exist("a"); // return true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the variable is an array or not then you can simply do this

```
if(is_array($urarray)){}
```

and if you want to check if an array is set or not

```
if(isset($urarray)){}
```

If you want to check if a key exists then do this

```
if (array_key_exists('key',$urarray)){}
```

If you want to check if value exists in an array then do this

```
if(in_array("value", $urarray))){}
```

Comment: isset() - Determine if a variable is set `and is not NULL`

Comment: @СеменихинМаксим Isnt array also a variable? Whats wrong if you check it exists or not.

Comment: it not check if var exists.  `variable is set and is not NULL`

Comment: @СеменихинМаксим So whats wrong it will give true if array is set and if not it will give false. And for this you downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

So As http://php.net/ says

> [array-key-exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) Checks if the given key or index exists in the array
>
> returns TRUE if the given key is set in the array.
>   key can be any value possible for an array index.
>
> Example #1 array_key_exists() example

```
<?php
$search_array = array('first' => 1, 'second' => 4);
if (array_key_exists('first', $search_array)) {
    echo "The 'first' element is in the array";
}
?>
```

> [in-array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) Checks if a value exists in an array
>
> Returns TRUE if value is found in the array, FALSE otherwise.
>
> Example #1 in_array() example

```
<?php
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
    echo "Got Irix";
}
if (in_array("mac", $os)) {
    echo "Got mac";
}
?>
```

**So basically one function checks for given array value and other checks given array key exist**

```
$arr = [
    `key1'=>'value1',
    'key2'=>'value2',
]
```